# What is the difference between the two sentences?

Tags: word-choice

> あの方はどなたですか。
>
> あの人はだれですか。

I was looking for a way to say: **"Who is that person?"**, And I found these two ways of doing it. What is the difference between these two?.

I found the first sentence in Minna no Nihongo book. Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> あの方{かた}はどなたですか。
>
> あの人{ひと}はだれですか。

The only difference is the overall politeness and respect being expressed.  The first sentence shows more respect toward the person being talked about.

「方」 is the honorific form of 「人」 and 「どなた」, of 「だれ」, respectively.

Thus, the second sentence is very plain and treats "that person" with no particular respect.